# Executing `terraform apply` on the same aws_s3_bucket resource twice have different results

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, localstack

In this file https://github.com/wentao-daommo/aws-local/blob/master/local.tf I'm setting up a aws_s3_bucket with localstack. The first time I run `terraform apply` it successfully created a bucket for me.

However, if I go run `terraform apply` or `terraform plan` again without change the tf file, it started to apply new changes that I didn't put in my tf file, with something like this

```html
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_s3_bucket.b will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
        id                          = "local-bucket"
        tags                        = {}
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - object_lock_configuration {
        }

      - replication_configuration {
        }

      - server_side_encryption_configuration {
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

If I proceed with change, what will happen is

```html
aws_s3_bucket.b: Refreshing state... [id=local-bucket]
aws_s3_bucket.b: Modifying... [id=local-bucket]

Error: error removing S3 bucket server side encryption: NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist
    status code: 404, request id: , host id:
```

I'm very confused about this behavior. I'm assuming running `terraform plan/apply` on the same tf file shouldn't trigger any changes. Am I missing anything?

Comment: This could be because you are using very old version of localstack. Current versions work as expected. Again, you are not providing important information in your question. What is your terraform version?

Comment: The localstack version is 0.10.5, and terraform version is 0.14.5. Let me try using the latest version of localstack to see if it solves the issue.

Comment: If you use new version, you will have to change all the ports, as I wrote in my previous answer.

Comment: After updating everything to the latest version and change all port numbers to 4566. Now everything is working fine. Thank you @Marcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using **very old version** (`0.10.5`) of `localstack`. The current version is `0.12.5`.

**Upgrading** `localstack` to the correct version resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you! Newer version fixed the issue.

Comment: @WentaoZheng No problem. Thank you for accepting:-)